# Как настроить автоматический размер изображения на body

Tags: html, css

У меня тег body полностью охвачен изображением [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда я изменяю размер экрана браузера изображение не охватывает весь экран
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вОТ код CSS :

```css
/* Bordered form */
body{
    background: url(images/4.jpg) no-repeat;
    
    -webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ и Chrome 4.0+ */
  
    background-size: 100%; /* Современные браузеры */

    max-width:100%;

    height:100%;;
}
```

Comment: А что должно произойти, когда экран больше изображения?

Comment: @stepanKasyanenko изображение должно расстянуться на 100 %

Comment: На 100% по горизонтали или вертикали? А если оно растянется больше, чем ее размер, то оно исказится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1920/1080) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS background-size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: не помогает ничто не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

задай высоту в vh и ширину vw.

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```